# Creating client using Ws import not generating service and port class

Tags: webservice-client

I generated  wsdl using Ws gen in my  application.  For  that  wsdl I tried  to  generate  client so used Ws import with Maven.  Client generation  is  successful  but  only request,  response,  exception,  object factory and  package classes  are  created.

There  is  no  class  for  the  service  reference.  What is the issue?

If service  class not needed  how to  call  the  service  from  my  client file

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you edit your question please to provide more information concerning the context: what development tool are you using to generate the WSDL and what options are you taking? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I have once seen this problem with Java SE '**wsimport**' command.
In my case service publisher's 'wsdl' SOAP port uses non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
Also, it's Service does not contain any usable ports.
It might show you some warning messages like this:

> [WARNING] Ignoring SOAP port "XXXSoap12HttpPort":
>   it uses non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
>   You must specify the "-extension" option to use this binding.
>   ...
>   [WARNING] Service "XXXService" does not contain any usable ports.
>   try running wsimport with -extension switch.
>   ...

Adding -**extension** switch to the '**wsimport**' command did the magic in this 
case.

```
wsimport -keep -p com.samlpe.jaxws.client -extension <WSDL URL>
```